# How to set default homepage in safari 6?

Tags: macos

Since downloading mountain lion and safari 6 I have lost the ability to set my home page.  in safari preferences there is the ability to tell it what you want for a home page but it does not take.  instead I always get this:  http://d3.zedo.com/jsc/d3/ff2.html?n=790;c=3603;s=2952;d=16;w=1024;h=768.  I want to know how to get rid of this and get my preference working instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind:

1. Reset Safari (in Safari menu), restart the application and try again
2. Quit Safari, rename `~/Library/Safari` to `~/Library/Safari.old` and try again

If the second options work, quit Safari again and copy `Bookmarks.plist` from `Safari.old` to the newly created `Safari` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm sure this isn't the easiest way to do it, but it should work!

1. Navigate to /Users/yourname/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
2. Open com.apple.Safari.plist
3. Find the "HomePage" key
4. Go into the value column for the "HomePage" key and set it to the desired homepage. Here's an image:

[image]

That's it!

Comment: If someone hasn't installed Xcode, you could also use defaults: `defaults write com.apple.Safari HomePage 'http://example.com'`.